# How can I address the element that called a function from within the function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying this HTML code:

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="setThemeColor(this.name)">Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="setThemeColor(this.name)">Black</button>
```

and script:

```
function setThemeColor(buttonName) {
    localStorage.themeColor = buttonName;
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = buttonName
    var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".theme");
    for (var button in themeButtons) {
        themeButtons[button].disabled = false;
    }
    // this.disabled = false;
    // element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

I am having a problem here setting the disabled state of the button that called the function. Can someone tell me how i can do this. I have tried two things but neither seem to work.

Comment: @DavidThomas Where are you?

Comment: `function setThemeColor(sender, buttonName)` ---> `setThemeColor(this, this.name)` . Well u just could pass the sender and get its name in the function reducing it to one parameter again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in a reference to your button instead of just the name:

**HTML**

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="setThemeColor(this)">Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="setThemeColor(this)">Black</button>
```

**JS**

```
function setThemeColor(button) {
    localStorage.themeColor = button.name;
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = button.name;
    var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".theme");
    for (var button in themeButtons) {
        themeButtons[button].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if I just one of the ways to set disabled or do I need both lines?

Comment: Yes, just use `setAttribute`. No need for the `disabled = false` line. Updated answer to reflect this

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("buttonid1").disabled=false;
```